# How can I insert long string into UTF8-collated varchar(N) column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, utf-8, varchar, sql-server-collation

I have data in `VARCHAR(MAX)` source, that I need to insert into another table as `VARCHAR(N)`.
The collation I need to use is UTF8 (specifically `Czech_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8`).
The problem is, even if I cut down the data up to maximum permissible length (using `LEFT` function, or `SUBSTRING`, or whatever), the insert fails for some data, with

> Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
> String or binary data would be truncated in table 'tablename', column 'columnname'. Truncated value: 'sometext'.

My question is, how to properly shorten the text, so it will fit, but still keep as much of it as possible?
The actual length of the string will depend on characters used, for latin-only texts the full length can be used. If there are a few accented characters, that will shorten the usable length by a bit. If the text is fully Unicode (non-latin script, e.g. Japanese), the usable length might be cut in half, or third.

Steps to reproduce:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [#tmpdl]
GO
CREATE TABLE [#tmpdl] ([Txt] VARCHAR(10) COLLATE Czech_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO [#tmpdl] ([Txt]) VALUES (LEFT('123456789abcd', 10)) --this works
GO
INSERT INTO [#tmpdl] ([Txt]) VALUES (LEFT('123456789ábcd', 10)) --this fails
GO
INSERT INTO [#tmpdl] ([Txt]) VALUES (LEFT(N'一二三四', 10)) --this also fails
GO
```

Comment: Why are you using `VARCHAR` rather than `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: If you `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;` then it seems to work as you want. Not sure I would recommend that though

Comment: @DavidG - UTF8 collations are normally used with `VARCHAR` - this gives the variable byte per character encoding. `NVARCHAR` will still use `UCS-2` encoding regardless of the collartion

Comment: The problem is that he SQL uses 16 bit characters and utf8 9 bity so you have to look for a clean convertion

Comment: @DavidG I'm using VARCHAR and UTF8 collation because the project requires it. These requirements are set in stone, I can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> even if I cut down the data up to maximum permissible length (using `LEFT` function, or `SUBSTRING`, or whatever), the insert fails for some data

With `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` you are cutting it down to the specified [number of *characters*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments), whereas the `10` in `varchar(10)` specifies the number of *bytes*, so after your truncation with `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` you are left with a string that may still have more bytes than 10 - which is the same, for the purpose of insertion, as if you never truncated it in the first place.

A simple way to truncate the string to a number of characters rather than bytes is to use `CAST` or `CONVERT`, because they [cut the string before the surrogate pair that doesn't fit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#supplementary-characters-surrogate-pairs) and [keep the original collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#output-collation):

```sql
INSERT INTO [#tmpdl] ([Txt]) VALUES (cast(N'123456789ábcd' COLLATE Czech_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 as varchar(10)));
INSERT INTO [#tmpdl] ([Txt]) VALUES (cast(N'一二三四' COLLATE Czech_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 as varchar(10)));
```

Do note that this requires SQL Server 2012 or later.

Comment: Thank you, this works!
I assumed that CAST or CONVERT would produce the same error, if the data was longer.

Comment: @habdl The error only happens on implicit truncations. Cast makes it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The `10` for a UTF8 value denotes the **bytes** that can be stored in the data type, *not* the number of characters. For the value `'123456789abcd'` these are all ANSI characters and 1 bytes in size. For `'123456789ábcd'`, however, the character `á` is *2 bytes* in size; this makes the datalength of the string you try to `INSERT` 11 bytes, not 10. It's a similar story for your last string, `'一二三四'`:

```sql
SELECT V.YourString,
       DATALENGTH(V.YourString),
       DATALENGTH(LEFT(V.YourString,10))
FROM (VALUES('123456789abcd' COLLATE Czech_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8),
            (CONVERT(varchar(20),N'123456789ábcd' COLLATE Czech_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8)),
            (CONVERT(varchar(20),N'一二三四' COLLATE Czech_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8)))V(YourString);
```

| YourString | Datalength | 10CharsDataLength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789abcd | 13 | 10 |
| 123456789ábc | 14 | 11 |
| 一二三四 | 12 | 12 |

You need to ensure that the length of the column you define has enough space for all the bytes, not the number of characters:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpdl
GO
CREATE TABLE [#tmpdl] ([Txt] VARCHAR(12) COLLATE Czech_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO [#tmpdl] ([Txt]) VALUES (LEFT('123456789abcd', 10)) --this works
GO
INSERT INTO [#tmpdl] ([Txt]) VALUES (LEFT('123456789ábcd', 10)) --this fails
GO
INSERT INTO [#tmpdl] ([Txt]) VALUES (LEFT(N'一二三四', 10)) --this also fails
GO
SELECT *
FROM  #tmpdl;
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpdl
```